# Winforms Non-Modal notifications

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, growl, non-modal

I have an app that currently shows a message box when the users saves that just says "Saved successfully". The problem is, user's tend to save frequently when using this app and the message box is a pain in the @$$. I'd like to have a little notification box that fades in and out and doesn't require user interaction, kind of like how Growl notifications work on a Mac.

Is there any .net library or free 3rd party application that does something like this?

Comment: Your user *expects* the data to be saved when she clicks Save.  Don't reminder her about expected outcomes, only about unexpected ones.

Comment: That's a reasonable idea I hadn't even considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use 3rd party libraries for something like this.

Crate a form for your notifications, styled as you wish.

When you need to notify, you can `Show` the form - to fade it in and out use the [`Opacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) property (using a timer to animate the changes).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this and see if it does what you want.
[Office 2003-like popup](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13547/An-Office-2003-like-popup-notifier)